# working with strings in c- expanding, replacing, storing and printing out strings

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have a simple C program that is supposed to expand the string `FX` according to the following rules:

```
X -> X+YF+
Y-> -FX-Y
```

The program is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void expandOnce( )
{
     char* s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
     int i=0;
     char str[]="FX";
     while(str[i]!='\0')
     {
           if(str[i]=='X')
           {
               s[i]="X+YF+";
           }
             if(str[i]=='Y')
           {
               s[i]="-FX-Y";
           }
           i++;
     }
          printf("%s",s);
}


void expandNtimes (int n)
{

for (int i =0; i < n; i++){
expandOnce();
}

}
int main(){
   expandNtimes(2);
    return 0;
}
```

If the program executes correctly, it should print out:

```
  FX+YF++-FX-YF+
```

This is after 2 expansions of `FX` using the above rules. 
Questions:
 1. How can you make this work without printing out gibberish?
 2. How can I return the expanded array from expandNtimes() and expandOnce() so that I can, for instance, use it in the main function?

I try this but I keep getting memory errors.

After your suggestions, I made the following changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NTIMES  2
#define MAXC  100

void expandOnce( )
{
    char s[MAXC];
     int i=0;
     s[0]='F';
     s[1]='X';

     while(s[i]!='\0')
     {
    if(s[i]=='X'){
    //shift all letters to the right by 5 steps
        for (i; i < MAXC; i++){ //warning: statement with no effect (Wunused value)
            s[i + 5]= s[i];
            if(s[i]=='\0'){
            break;}
                  }
    //Fill in the expansion
        s[i]='X';
        s[i+1] ='+';
        s[i+2] ='Y';
        s[i+3]='F';
        s[i+4] ='+';
    }
  if(s[i]=='Y'){
  //shift all letters to the right by 5 steps
        for (i; i < MAXC; i++){ //warning: statement with no effect (Wunused value)
            s[i + 5]=s[i];
            if(s[i]=='\0'){
            break;}
                }
    //Fill in the expansion
        s[i]='-';
        s[i+1] ='F';
        s[i+2] ='X';
        s[i+3]='-';
        s[i+4] ='Y';
    }
             i++;
     }
          printf("%s\n",s);
           printf("Me\n");
}


void expandNtimes (int n)
{

for (int i =0; i < n; i++){
expandOnce();
}

}
int main(){
expandOnce();
expandNtimes(NTIMES);
return 0;
}
```

Both of my for loops have a warning `warning: statement with no effect (Wunused value)` which I do not understand. Finally, I get this error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Is it allowed to do a for-loop inside a while-loop?

Comment: `s[i]="X+YF+";` is an error . If you do not see a diagnostic message from your compiler then the first thing you should do is investigate how to enable its diagnostics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh Boy... Do you have a whole list of "you can't do that..." in your code.

To begin with there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714).

```
char *s = malloc (sizeof *s * 100);
```

is all that is needed (note: if you always use `sizeof dereference_pointer` you will always have your type size correct.

This brings up another point, if you need constants `#define` one (or more) or use a global `enum` to accomplish the same thing, e.g.

```
#define NTIMES  2
#define MAXC  100
```

or

```
enum { NTIMES = 2, MAXC = 100 };
```

Then you can use them like,

```
char *s = malloc (sizeof *s * MAXC);
```

and

```
expandNtimes(NTIMES);
```

By defining constants, you then have one convenient place at the top of your code to make changes if needed in the future and not have to pick through each allocation or function call changing all your hardcoded *magic numbers*.

**Your Memory Leak**

You allocate for `s` in `expandOnce`, but never `free` `s` and don't return a pointer so that it could be later freed in `main()` (or any other calling function).

You should include `free (s);` after `printf("%s",s);` (which you should also include a `newline` in to prevent multiple outputs from running together, and so that your program is POSIX compliant -- outputting a final `'\n'`), e.g. `printf("%s\n",s);`

Moreover, *"Why are you dynamically allocating anyway?"* Just use a fixed buffer, you are not trying to return it. Just use:

```
char s[MAXC] = "";
```

**`s` is Uninitialized and You Leave `s[0]` Uninitialized**

`s[i]="X+YF+";` and `s[i]="-FX-Y";` write 4-characters to `s` from index `1`. `s[0]` is never initialized which causes any subsequent attempt to read from `s` invoke *Undefined Behavior*. You cannot simply assign the pointer to *string literal* `"X+YF+";` to a character `s[i]` -- **your compiler should be screaming warnings and errors at you**.

You can copy the literal to `s` with:

```
strcpy (s, "X+YF+");
```

or you can simply loop repeatedly copying as you go, e.g.

```
int i;
for (i = 0; str[i]; i++) /* loop over each char in str */
    s[i] = str[i];       /* assign to s */
s[i] = 0;                /* don't forget to nul-terminate s */
```

**Compile with Warnings Enabled**

Always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles cleanly without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra` to your `gcc` or `clang` compile string. (add `-pedantic` for several additional warnings). For `clang`, instead you can use `-Weverything`. For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windoze), add `/W3` (or use `/Wall` to enable all warnings).

Read and understand each warning. They will identify any problems, and the exact line on which they occur. You can learn as much about coding by simply listening to what your compiler is telling you as you can from most tutorials.

Put these suggestions to use and then edit your question (or ask a new one) if you have further problems.

---

**Additional Comments After Edit**

Gakuo, it is obvious you are still struggling to sort out string/character array handling in order to make the expansions work. As I mentioned in the comments, whenever you have a problem like this, *do not* pick up the keyboard and start pecking away hoping that you can tinker long enough that divine intervention will somehow guide you to a solution (it won't...).

Instead first pick up a 8 1/2 x 11 sheet of paper (graph paper works really well) and write out your original string, and then plan each step required to get you from your original string to the final string you need (don't forget to represent the `'\0'` in your layout as well)

For example, you could start with your original string:

```
+---+---+---+
| F | X |\0 |
+---+---+---+
```

The next step would be to represent the shift to make room for your expansion (you leave the original character in place since you will simply overwrite it):

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| F | X |   |   |   |   |\0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Now it is a matter of copying `"X+YF+"` to the position of `'X'` resulting in:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| F | X | + | Y | F | + |\0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Then simply repeat this process until you have fully exanded N times. As you do, you will be able to determine the pattern for expanding N times -- and that is when it is time to pick up the keyboard.

For your case, rather than manually looping everything, make use of `memmove` and `memcpy` to help shift and copy within the string. (you are free to manually shift and copy by looping -- as long as you can find more letters for you loop variable than just `'i'`). Letting the memory functions help, you could do something like:

(**note:** edited to accommodate changing length of `s` in `expandonce()`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NTIMES  2
#define MAXC  100

#define SDEF "FX"       /* string (default) */
#define XEXP "X+YF+"    /* X expansion */
#define YEXP "-FX-Y"    /* Y expansion */

/* returns pointer to 1-past last expansion on success, NULL otherwise */
char *expandonce (char *s)
{
    char *p = s,
        *expanded = NULL;
    size_t lxexp = strlen (XEXP),
        lyexp = strlen (YEXP);

    while (*p) {
        if (*p == 'X') {        /* handle 'X' found */
            size_t lens = strlen (s);               /* get new length of s */
            if (MAXC > lens + lxexp) {                  /* room to expand? */
                size_t lenp = strlen (p);               /* total to shift */
                /* shift chars to right of 'X' by lxexp-1 including '\0' */
                memmove (p + lxexp, p + 1, lenp + lxexp - 1);
                memcpy (p, XEXP, lxexp);                /* copy expansion */
                p += lxexp;                             /* add offset */
                expanded = p;                           /* set return */
            }
        }
        else if (*p == 'Y') {   /* handle 'Y' found */
            size_t lens = strlen (s);                   /* same for 'Y' */
            if (MAXC > lens + lyexp) {
                size_t lenp = strlen (p);
                memmove (p + lyexp, p + 1, lenp + lyexp - 1);
                memcpy (p, YEXP, lyexp);
                p += lyexp;
                expanded = p;
            }
        }
        else    /* handle all other chars */
            p++;
    }

    return expanded;
}

/* returns number of successful expansion loops */
int expandntimes (char *s, int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    char *p = s;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if ((p = expandonce (s)) == NULL)
            break;

    return i;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char str[MAXC] = "";
    int n = 0;

    if (argc > 1 && strlen (argv[1]) < MAXC - 1)
        strcpy (str, argv[1]);
    else
        strcpy (str, SDEF);

    printf ("string: %s\nX_exp : %s\nY_exp : %s\n\n", str, XEXP, YEXP);

    n = expandntimes (str, NTIMES);

    if (n == 0) {
        fputs ("error: no expansions possible.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("%d expansions => %s\n", n, str);

    return 0;
}
```

(note: this is a minimum example -- you should verify that all corner cases are covered as you step through your design)

**Example Use/Output**

Your example:

```
$ ./bin/expand2 "FX"
string: FX
X_exp : X+YF+
Y_exp : -FX-Y

2 expansions => FX+YF++-FX-YF+
```

A slightly different string:

```
$ ./bin/expand2 "XY"
string: XY
X_exp : X+YF+
Y_exp : -FX-Y

2 expansions => X+YF++-FX-YF+-FX+YF+--FX-Y
```

Comment: I have taken your suggestions into account and made some changes. However, I still get an error and some warnings and have edited my question to indicate that. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @Gakuo give me a bit to look at it and I'll drop an edit to my answer and let you know.

Comment: @Gakuo - you have got to stop using `'i'` for all loop variables. This is a recipe for disaster. You can't simply shift `s[i + 5]= s[i];` (what happens to the character already at `s[i + 5]` - you overwrite it without saving it first). The only way to write an expansion routine is to first pull out an 8 1/2x11 sheet of paper. Write out your original string in big block letters. Below it, write out the new string you are trying to obtain, and then step-by-step write out the statements needed to get from the original to the new string.

Comment: When I run your program on codeblocks, I get the same fault segmentation fault(core dumped) error. :(

Comment: @Gakuo - depending on the length of the string, you could run into problems by failing to account for the changing length of `s` in `expandonce()`. I have made changes above.

Comment: Now it works. I have to understand its working. It is quite complex for me :)

Comment: I get it, and I don't mind helping, but it really is one of those things where you just have to *s.l.o.w..d.o.w.n* and take it byte-by-byte to validate that every shift, every test, every copy results in exactly what you need to have happen. When you had the last segfault, it became apparent that you were entering input longer than `"FX"` so I looked at what would happen for longer strings (thus my original note about the code being a *minimum*). That is just one of the many conditions you have to try and foresee when you write your algorithms. Glad it worked, and good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 0):

You getting memory errors because you try to write in memory where are you not supposed to do anything.if you want to append string you must use strcat() function! Line s[i]="X+YF+"; will never compile because you try to write multiple characters in place where is allowed only one character. i think it is better to make s global and append charracters one by one to s with strcat until you make string. You can access to global variables in main.Then print string s.

Comment: I do not understand how strcat() will solve this. Given str1 and str2 strcat(str1, str2) will result in str1str2 but in my case I need to substitute a letter with another set of characters.

Comment: if you want to replace character you can do it only if access to it with s[i] but you only can set it to one letter so s[i]="Y" is correct you cant replace multiple characters with s[i]. this is pointer to only ONE character.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I welcome any other approach that works. It does not have to involve character arrays, so long as it works and possible suggestions of making it efficient on both memory and execution times if I am to use it on extensive string expansion.

Comment: I changed my program to make it copy just a single letter in one array slot. I still get the fault segmentation (core dumped) error. My question edits indicate it